# Centering a character inside a DIV

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to center a Character inside a div both vertically and horizontally.
I had used the following piece of css to achieve so.

```
  margin : 0 auto; //attempt1
  text-align:center; //attempt2
```

Both did not work, Attempt 2  simply align the character horizontally.
But i need to align it vertically too.

[My Code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/A3kw4/1/)

Any clues to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try to google it? You're not the first one with this problem.

Comment: Is the height of the div fixed or fluid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you fix it:

First wrap the character in an element:

```
<div id="DivMenu">
   <div id="character">R</div>
</div>
```

Then set the following CSS:

```
#DivMenu{
   ...
   text-align:center;
}

#character{
   position:relative;
   top:50%;
   margin-top:-10px
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/A3kw4/4/)

Comment: Its working.. but Why did you hard code with margin-top? will it be compatible in all resolutions?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: The margin top is proportional to half the height of the character, so that it is centered properly. It will work on all resolutions as long as the character itself has the same height (ex. if you change the font size you must change the margin too).

Comment: This is not a very good solution, since you rely on the `font-size` to make your `margin-top` work properly, let alone the `line-height`.

Comment: Any chance that using `-0.5em` rather than an explicit measure in `px` will address the relative font-size issue?

Comment: @JCOC611: Yes, but mine requires that you know the `width` and `height` of the element you want to center while yours requires that you know the `font-size`, `line-height`, even the `display`, the `border`...

Comment: @RémiBreton: not really, as all of those properties affect the `width` and `height` of the element. Therefore, one only really needs to know those. We are using pretty much the *exact* same method to center anyway.

Comment: @JCOC611 Yeah, I still think there is a minor difference between the two, but I agree, we're pretty much using the same method.

Answer (score 1):

Still another simple idea for the vertical centering is to drop the height property and add padding to the top and bottom, each of which is half your original height. Of course, for the horizontal centering, use text-align:

```
text-align: center;
padding-top: 6%;
padding-bottom: 6%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser horizontal alignment is a little tricky.

In the context of the example youve provided you can use:

```
line-height:100px;
```

For other context you will need to use javascript and bind:

```
$.fn.vAlignBlock = function() {
        return this.each(function(i){
                var ah = $(this).height();
                var ph = $(this).parent().height();
                var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
        $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
        });
};


$.fn.vAlignInlineBlock = function() {
    return this.each(function(i) {
        var h = $(this).height();
        var oh = $(this).outerHeight();
        var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;
        $(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px");
        $(this).css("top", "50%");
        $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A technique I use often is to wrap the thing you want centered in a `block` element. It requires that you know the width and height of what you want to be centered. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/ufEKK/1/).

```
<div>
    <span>R</span>
</div>
```

Then you style the `span` element (or whatever you'd like, but keep it semantic!) like this:

```
span {
    width:10px;
    height:20px;
    margin:-10px 0 0-5px; /* margin-top is minus half your height, margin-left is minus half your width */
    top:50%; left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
}
```

If you don't want useless elements to the `DOM` for presentational purposes, you can match the `line-height` of your text node to the height of your container. The downside is that if your text spans across two lines, it will inevitably screw up your design since the `line-height` is abnormally high. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/aLzUh/).

```
div {
    [...]
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HLet2/1/

```
<div id="DivMenu">
    <p>R</p>
</div>


#DivMenu
{
position:absolute;
-webkit-border-radius: 999px;
-moz-border-radius: 999px;
border-radius: 999px;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
background: #ccc;
border: 2px solid #2F2E2E;
width: 10%;
height: 12%;

}

#DivMenu p
{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:50%;
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

A different method would be to use good old `line-height` to create the vertical alignment. The idea is to make the line-height the same as the height. Then `text-align: center` for the horizontal. This works in all major browsers I've tested and is the simplest solution.

The alignment properties are separated from the rest of the styles in this example:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

#DivMenu
{   
    background: #CCC;
    border: 2px solid #2F2E2E;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="DivMenu">
    R
</div>
</body>
</html>
```